# WooCommerce - Get the Subscription id from the Order ID

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, woocommerce-subscriptions

I'm trying to get the **`subscription id`** from the action hook **`woocommerce_order_status_changed`**.

It gives me the **`order id`** which is changed with every switch the customer makes.

For example: If the **`subscription id`** is **`10`**, the original **`order id`** is **`9`**.

Now every switch the customer made generates a new order id, which the action above gives you. At this point I have the **`$customer_id`**, **`$order_id`**, and the original **`post id`** which is **`9`**,

How I can get the **`subscription id`** of the current order?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use dedicated function [**`wcs_get_subscriptions_for_order()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/functions/order-cart-functions/#section-2) which will retrieve $subscription IDs.

So this could be your code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'action_order_status_changed');
function action_order_status_changed( $order_id ){
    $subscriptions_ids = wcs_get_subscriptions_for_order( $order_id, array( 'order_type' => 'any' ) );
    // We get all related subscriptions for this order
    foreach( $subscriptions_ids as $subscription_id => $subscription_obj )
        if($subscription_obj->order->id == $order_id) break; // Stop the loop

    // The subscription ID: $subscription_id 
    // The An instance of the Subscription object: $subscription_obj 
    // ...
}
```

Comment: A note for anyone reading this: I had to set the params for the function as `wcs_get_subscriptions_for_order( $order_id, array( 'order_type' => 'any' ) )` to get this to work. Without the second parameter it was not working for me ( see function `add_subscriptions_to_view_order_templates()` in class-wc-subscriptions-order.php file in the woocommerce-subscriptions plugin which does the same thing). I'm using WC 3.3.5 and Wordpress 4.9.4

Comment: @Sarah Thanks for your note…

Comment: @Sarah thanks for your note, it really help full. thanks a lot :)